# Go access smartphone connected to PC

Tags: go

I'm trying to copy files from a pc to a smartphone. The problem is, that Windows doesn't assign the phone a drive-letter. It just shows up as 'Phone' (the device name).

The path shown in the Explorer is 'This PC\Phone\SD card,' which is not a path that a go programm can use.

Is there a way to directly copy the files or do I have to use ADB?

Comment: What path would you use in Powershell?

Comment: @Adrian I meant ADB, sorry for the mistake